# javascript create array from .replace results

Tags: javascript, arrays, browser, replace

hope someone has a idea.
I have a .replace function for html sites like,

```
var replacedText = text.replace(/one/g, "something")
        .replace(/two/g, "something2")
        .replace(/three/g, "something3")
        .replace(/four/g, "something4")
if (replacedText !== text) {
            element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
```

the replace works in my case really good. 
But now i need a array which shows the results like
I replaced something2 =4times, something3 = 5times,...
only if there more then one replace

```
result = [["something",4],["something3",2],..]
```

is there a easy way?
thanks

Comment: There isn't an easy way. You have to try something, and then we can help you if it doesn't work. You can do it using [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). `'ababab'.match(/ab/g)` outputs `['ab', 'ab', 'ab']`

Comment: the problem is if i use .match and there is in the html a string like 
"something3" then my .match results a 1 but this string is not from my .replace it was still there.. 
so in reality may my replace does noting and the match can output results and this is not my need!

Comment: You have to use match to count the matches and replace to replace the string. Not sure what else I can tell you here. I guess I can tell you that you can't do it in one statement as you are trying to do. And don't explain something with words, post the code that you tried.

Comment: You need to do `.match(/one/g)` *before* you do the replacement. That will tell you how many matches there are, which is how many strings will be replaced by that regexp.

Comment: barmar you right ...
thanks guys